# Merging two xml files based on conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've run into a scenario which seems to exceed my skills in XSLT. The problem is the following: I've got two input files tuplelist.xml and orderlist.xml. The former contains some information which should be added to the second file (on which I'm running my .xsl file on).
The files look like this:

Edit: the files now contain a real sample which should have the distance added.
After adding the changes suggested in the answer below, the output basically contains a reproduction of my orderlist.xml, but without the added distance elements.

tuplelist.xml

```
<TU:tuplelist xmlns:TU="www.tuplelist.com">
    <tuple xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <start>Regensburg, Germany</Start>
        <destination>Bremerhaven, Germany</destination>
        <distance>736 km</distance>
    </tuple>
    <!-- more <tuple> Elements here -->
</tuplelist>
```

orderlist.xml

```
<orderlist xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <order>
        <nr>Transportauftrag</nr>
        <sender>
            <name>somename</name>
            <street>somestreet</street>
            <number>somenumber</number>
            <zip>somezip</zip>
            <town>Regensburg</town>
            <country>Germany</country>
        </sender>
        <recipient>
            <name>aname</name>
            <street>astreet</street>
            <number>anumber</number>
            <zip>azip</zip>
            <town>Bremerhaven</town>
            <country>Germany</country>
        </recipient>
    </order>
    <!-- more <order> elements here -->
</orderlist>
```

Now what I want to do is add the fitting  element to each . What I'm trying to do is compare each  to each sender/town and each  to each recipient/town, as it can be seen in my current xslt:

merge.xlst

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:OL="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  xmlns:TL="www.tuplelist.com" xmlns:T="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">

<xsl:variable name="TL" select="document('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/tuplelist.xml')" />

<xsl:template match="OL:orderlist">
    <orderlist>
        <xsl:for-each select="./OL:order">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>

            <xsl:variable name="sta" select="./OL:sender/OL:town/text()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="dest" select="./OL:recipient/OL:town/text()"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="document($TL)/TL:tuplelist/T:tuple">
                <xsl:if test="starts-with(./OL:start, sta)">
                    <xsl:if test="starts-with(./OL:destination, dest)">
                        <distance>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="./T:distance/text()"/>
                        </distance>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </orderlist>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think I got my namespaces right and can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong, would you please help me out?
Note: I'm running this within the WSO2 ESB and can't actually see the output of my xslt since it only prints that there is an error.

Comment: Can you specify what error you are getting?

Comment: As I said, that's a bit difficult. The actual error message I'm getting is produced by the ESB when it tries to envelope the XSLT Output into a message. What the message says is basically that it's getting unexcepting characters ("T" when expecting "<" at some point in the "prolog" of the xslt output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want

```
        <xsl:variable name="sta" select="OL:sender/OL:town"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dest" select="OL:recipient/OL:town"/>

        <xsl:copy-of select="$TL/TL:tuplelist/T:tuple[starts-with(OL:start, $sta) and starts-with(OL:destination, $dest)]/T:distance">
```

instead of

```
        <xsl:variable name="sta" select="./OL:sender/OL:town/text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dest" select="./OL:recipient/OL:town/text()"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="document($TL)/TL:tuplelist/T:tuple">
            <xsl:if test="starts-with(./OL:start, sta)">
                <xsl:if test="starts-with(./OL:destination, dest)">
                    <distance>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="./T:distance/text()"/>
                    </distance>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

And it might be safer or even necessary to use `<xsl:variable name="TL" select="document('file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/tuplelist.xml')" />` instead of `<xsl:variable name="TL" select="document('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/tuplelist.xml')" />`.

Additionally, if you want to use

```
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
```

then you need to add a template that makes sure the child nodes the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` processes are handled, the usual way is to include the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in your stylesheet.

As an alternative, you can simply copy the child nodes with e.g.

```
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
```

And you probably want to put the code finding the matched distance inside of the `xsl:copy` and not below it.

Finally, the input XML has the namespace `xmlns:TU="www.tuplelist.com"` while your XSLT declares `xmlns:TL="www.tupelliste.com"` you will need to make sure you have the same URLs `xmlns:TL="www.tuplelist.com"`.

With all those corrections I have arrived at

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:OL="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  xmlns:TL="www.tuplelist.com" xmlns:T="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">

    <xsl:param name="tl-url" select="'test2016060901.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="TL" select="document($tl-url)" />

    <xsl:template match="OL:orderlist">
        <orderlist>
            <xsl:for-each select="OL:order">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="sta" select="OL:sender/OL:town"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="dest" select="OL:recipient/OL:town"/>

                    <xsl:copy-of select="$TL/TL:tuplelist/T:tuple[starts-with(OL:start, $sta) and starts-with(OL:destination, $dest)]/T:distance"/>
                </xsl:copy>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </orderlist>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms

```
<TU:tuplelist xmlns:TU="www.tuplelist.com">
    <tuple xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <start>New York, Country</start>
        <destination>Phoenix, SomeCountry</destination>
        <distance>190 km</distance>
    </tuple>
    <!-- more <tuple> Elements here -->
</TU:tuplelist>
```

and

```
<orderlist xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <order>
        <nr>Transportauftrag</nr>
        <sender>
            <name>somename</name>
            <street>somestreet</street>
            <number>somenumber</number>
            <zip>somezip</zip>
            <town>New York</town>
            <country>somecountry</country>
        </sender>
        <recipient>
            <name>aname</name>
            <street>astreet</street>
            <number>anumber</number>
            <zip>azip</zip>
            <town>Phoenix</town>
            <country>acountry</country>
        </recipient>
    </order>
    <!-- more <order> elements here -->
</orderlist>
```

into

```
<orderlist xmlns:OL="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xmlns:TL="www.tuplelist.com" xmlns:T="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><order xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <nr>Transportauftrag</nr>
        <sender>
            <name>somename</name>
            <street>somestreet</street>
            <number>somenumber</number>
            <zip>somezip</zip>
            <town>New York</town>
            <country>somecountry</country>
        </sender>
        <recipient>
            <name>aname</name>
            <street>astreet</street>
            <number>anumber</number>
            <zip>azip</zip>
            <town>Phoenix</town>
            <country>acountry</country>
        </recipient>
    <distance xmlns:TU="www.tuplelist.com">190 km</distance></order></orderlist>
```

I guess you want some namespace clean-up by doing

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:OL="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xmlns:TL="www.tuplelist.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="TL">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="tl-url" select="'test2016060901.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="TL" select="document($tl-url)"/>

    <xsl:template match="OL:orderlist">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="OL:order">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="sta" select="OL:sender/OL:town"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="dest" select="OL:recipient/OL:town"/>

                    <xsl:copy-of
                        select="$TL/TL:tuplelist/OL:tuple[starts-with(OL:start, $sta) and starts-with(OL:destination, $dest)]/OL:distance"
                    />
                </xsl:copy>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the match is found.

Comment: Do you mean [starts-with(TL:tuplelist/T:tuple/T:start, $sta) and starts-with(TL:tuplelist/T:tuple/T:destination, $dest)] ?

Comment: @user3190009, see the edit that indicates which code to replace

Comment: I have to ask again, should it not be
<xsl:copy-of select="$TL/TL:tuplelist/T:tuple[starts-with(T:start, $sta) and starts-with(T:destination, $dest)]/T:distance">
since start and Destination are childs of <tuple>?

Comment: You have both prefixes `T` and `OL` bound to the same namespace so it shouldn't matter which prefix you use, I simply used the same as in your posted code, only trying to correct the problems (`document($TL)`) and trying to simplify all those expressions as far as possible.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried it out and it doesn't seem to work. It produces some output (which I cant see) but my console prints the same error as above. Is there a simple way to test an XSLT with multiple Input files? I only know of the online tools but those seem to only support a single XML Input.

Comment: It depends what you consider simple, most IDEs nowadays have XML and XSLT support built in and allow you to run an XSLT transformation, as do some programming editors (perhaps with the help of a plugin you install first). And of course you can run some XSLT processor like Xalan or Saxon from the command line. There are also specialized XML IDEs like Altova XMLSpy or like oXygen, StylusStudio. As for "doesn't work", do you continue to get an error, or no merging at all, or merged elements in the wrong position?

Comment: After your comment I realised that I could simply run it in Notepad++. Doing so resulted in the following:

<orderlist xmlns:OL="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xmlns:TL="www.tuplelist.com" xmlns:T="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<order xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<!-- now there is all the content of the original order but without any tags and no distance -->
</order> </orderlist>

Comment: @user3190009, see the edit for some further improvements, I will need to check with code why the match does not work. Can you edit the question and the input sample to show some sample data where the values actually do match?

Comment: @user3190009, there is also a problem with a namespace difference which I have pointed out in a further edit.

Comment: the different namespaces were a typo on my side. The namespaces locally were correct though.

Comment: @user3190009, I have posted a small but complete XSLT snippet together with two corrected XML input snippets and the output I get. The matching `distance` element is found.